# Open file and save

Tags: c#, webclient, download

I want to download a file and save it locally without any pop ups for user to choose location since its predefined. File format will most probably be pdf. Download file path will be an url and I want to save it locally. Do I go to work like this:

```
string fileName = "http://mail.example.com/download.asp?saveFile=example.pdf";  

BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open));  

string path = "C:\\Domains\\shared.example.com\\pdf\\example.pdf";  

using (BinaryWriter Writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path,FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))  
{  
    Writer.Write(binReader);  
}
```

Comment: It looks like C#/.NET but you should specify the language/framework...

Comment: consider using better names. binReader -> binWriter instead of Writer. fileName which is a url (or path). I suggest, String downloadPath, savePath

Comment: I do follow descriptive naming conventions that was just a hasty example my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(filename, path);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not working that way...you'll have to use the [WebRequest-Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28VS.71%29.aspx) for acquiring the file.

Bobby

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
new WebClient().DownloadFile("http://url/name.pdf", @"C:\locationOnFilesystem.pdf");
```

You can use `DownloadFileAsync` to do this without blocking your main thread. Attach event handlers to the WebClient to report progress, like `DownloadProgressChanged` and `DownloadFileCompleted`.

Answer (score -1):

You should tag which language you're using.

Also I don't believe browsers would let a file be downloaded without asking the user first as this is a security issue. You could easily throw viruses on to people's computers without them knowing.

Comment: Actually, he never mentioned using a browser. And you can download _anything_ from the web without the user knowing, as long nothing stands in the way (Firewall or Virus-Scanner).

Comment: I'll keep that in mind with my next post.
*Note to self to avoid confusion be more descriptive*